# how to remove attribute value from custom search form in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, module, webforms, drupal-7

I have installed custom search Module for search block. in the search form there is one text field having **value** attribute with **null** value. which is showing the Accessibility issue, that's why i want to remove it. what should i do for this. please help.

can any one solve this type of issue.

Please see the source code snapshot.

[snapshot of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiFRD.png)

Comment: We need to see your custom php code , not your html .We can't help on custom development without to see your code

Answer (score 0):

For text fields the value attribute is forcibly added in [`theme_textfield()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_textfield/7), so the only way would be to override that function in your theme and remove that bit of code:

```
function YOURTHEME_textfield($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'text';
  // remove value form array
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'size', 'maxlength'));
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-text'));

  $extra = '';
  if ($element['#autocomplete_path'] && !empty($element['#autocomplete_input'])) {
    drupal_add_library('system', 'drupal.autocomplete');
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-autocomplete';

    $attributes = array();
    $attributes['type'] = 'hidden';
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#autocomplete_input']['#id'];
    $attributes['value'] = $element['#autocomplete_input']['#url_value'];
    $attributes['disabled'] = 'disabled';
    $attributes['class'][] = 'autocomplete';
    $extra = '<input' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
  }

  $output = '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';

  return $output . $extra;
}
```

Hope this helps your...

Comment: Thanks, do not work for me. can i change this directly in include/form.inc file.

Comment: Don't change the core file

Comment: Nope only in theming you can

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it by using jquery. Use the below code.

```
$('.custom-search-box').removeAttr('value');
```

i guess this helps you.